# Magento2.3.3 Payflow Pro CC method not working, clicking on place order button loader keeps spinning but order doesn't place

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3.3, payment-gateway, credit-card, paypal-payflow-pro

I am using magento 2.3.3 and I have enabled default magento Payflow Pro with Express checkout payment method. I have configured all required paypal merchant account details in admin area within payment method settings.

Now, if I try to place order with Express checkout method then it works fine. However, when I try to place order with credit card method then first paypal authorization request fired successfully with 0 amount. But then nothing happens and loader keeps spinning. I have also enabled debug mode and check logs in all log files but nothing relevant error information found.

This is default magento and I believe that there is no problem with paypal merchant account details configured at admin side otherwise Express method won't work. I have also found this issue created by someone on github magento2 repo at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4408. However, no one had provided any exact solution over there as well.

Does anybody faced this issue in any project? Please help me as I am trying to resolve it since last few days.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After lot of googling, I have also got multiple findings which can be the solution and might help someone looking for the same issue. Here I am listing all those one by one:

**1)** You need to configure Return URL Method in your manager.paypal.com account:
Service Settings -> Hosted Checkout Pages -> Set Up -> Payment Confirmation section.

**2)** Go to your manager.paypal.com,

**i)** Then go at "Home --> Service Summary --> Hosted Checkout Pages -->Set up" and set Cancel URL Method to POST;

**ii)** Return URL Method: POST;

**iii)** Enable Secure Token: Yes;

This will capture the real amount after authorize the amount 0, this action works immediately.

**3)** Go to "Paypal Manager --> Account Administration --> Transaction Settings" and set Allow reference transactions to Yes. This action will take effect in an hour.

Hope this might be useful to others.

Comment: Hello, Pratik Navapara, for your information helpful to PaypalPayments Pro  ( https://snipboard.io/mvQDiy.jpg ) ?

Comment: @zus, Yes this question is posted for PayPal Payments Pro CC Method..

Comment: Could you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/321232/57334

Comment: @zus, did you try all 3 solutions I posted above? One of them should work fine for you.

Comment: Hi Pratik, this solution works but on the 2nd load. On the first load it just keeps loading. This is on version 2.4. Can you please advice?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

The issue was fixed by Magento team. The fix was delivered into magento/magento2:2.4-develop branch(es). Related commit(s):

abdb45844fd3862a8a2f852fb34d35cc0e958829 
8ed20d151301484271b03755006e203e80ef76eb 
8211eb79022e2167dad38349c63bb9c36279e34d 
6d6af36f4fb31dfe7f585061d34332ed0819fe1a 
45b9e193ddd8a413cb041976de6f1d9da5f53d5f 
The fix will be available with the upcoming 2.4.0 release.

Comment: can you please provide the link to github?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the never completing PayFlow checkout page.

Payflow posts back to paypal/transparent/redirect/

but if you have a store switcher, it may add information to the returned link which screws things up.

I added the following to pages to exclude under the store switcher tab

paypal/*

Hope this helps you or others, not all browsers will show any type of error, no log errors, nothing just an ever spinning spinner.

Answer (score -1):

It may sound like a stupid question but where can I find the store switcher tab in Magento 2 ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208664)