# Magento 2.3 - Paypal - Other Paypal Payment Solution - Payments Pro - keep loading at checkout page - CC Payment

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.4, 404, paypal-payments-pro

After configuring Paypal Payments Pro, direct PayPal payment mode working, if pay using CC page keep loading, and my console network,

[image]

**Log error :** cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Paypal\Controller\Transparent\Response)

Response.php => https://justpaste.it/5kot8

Payments Pro Setup :

[image]
[image]

How to set up in the right way?

Comment: did you found any solution for this?

Comment: any solution on this?